# Design Pattern for data import of various source types and to various destination types

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have to design and build an import script (in C#) that can handle the following:

- read data from various sources (XML, XSLX, CSV)
- verify data
- write the data to various object types (customer, address)

The data will come from a number of sources but a source will always have one import format (either csv, xml, xslx). Import formats can vary from source to source. New import formats may be added in the future.
The destination object types are always the same (customer, addres and some more).

I've been thinking about using generics and I read something about the factory pattern but I'm a pretty big noob in this area so any advice is more than welcome.

What is an appropriate design pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: Keep it simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are going overboard with fancy concepts was too soon.  Generics - when you see a case use them, but otherwise don't worry.  Factory pattern - way too much flexibility ( and added confusion ) for this yet.

Keep it simple. Use fundamental practices.

1. Try to imagine the common things between doing a read for XML, a read for CSV whatever.  Things like, next record, next line.  Since New formats may be added, try to imagine commonality that the to be determined format would have with the known ones. Use this commonality and define an 'interface' or a contract that all formats must adhere to.   Though they adhere to the common ground, they all may have their specific internal rules.
2. For validating the data, try to provide a way to easily plug in new or different validator code blocks.  So again, try to define an interface where each validator, responsible for a particular kind of data construction adheres to a contract.
3. For creating the data constructions you will probably be constrained by whoever designs the suggested output objects more than anything.  Try to figure out what the next step for the data objects is, and are there any optimizations you can make by knowing the final use.   For example if you know the objects are going to be used in an interactive application, you could help the developer of that app by providing 'summations' or counts of the objects or other kinds of derived information.

I'd say most of these are Template patterns or Strategy patterns.  The whole project would be an Adapter pattern.

Comment: +1, especially for the first paragraph (and it is nice to see that you came to the same conclusion as me in the last paragraph).

Comment: Also keep in mind the architecture of the whole project, to adapt one format to another.  Can you imagine any situation where someone might use just one part of that in another project?  E.G. Maybe a new data validator comes on the market, and it works only with SQL server.  So now you just want ot read the custom XML and put in SQL server, skipping the rest of the steps.

Comment: To facilitate this, not only should the pieces have their internal contracts that they adhere to, there should be a set of contracts that define the interaction **between the pieces**.

Comment: @AndyzSmith - I have the identical problem in my code. I understood all about your code except the Adapter pattern. When you said the whole project is an example of Adapter pattern can you illustrate that ?

Answer (score 9):

The obvious thing is to apply [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Have a generic base class `ReadStrategy` and for each input format a subclass like `XmlReadStrategy`, `CSVReadStrategy` etc. This will allow you to change the import processing independently from the verfication processing and the output processing.

Depending on the details it may be also possible to keep most parts of the import generic and exchange only parts of the input processing (for example, reading of one record). This may lead you to [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: Does it mean that when using the strategy pattern, I have to create separate methods for converting the objects (customer, address) from the source to the destination. What I would like to do is read, convert and validate each object and put it in a list so that the list can later be saved to the database.

Comment: @jao: well, if you read my answer again, you see that my suggestion was to create "ReadStrategy", not a "ConvertStrategy". So you only have to write different methods for *reading* objects (or whatever additional part of your process is individual for the specific file format).

Answer (score 7):

A suitable pattern for an importing utility that you may need to extend in the future would be to use MEF - you can keep memory use low by loading the converter you need on the fly from a lazy list, create MEF imports that are decorated with attributes that help select the right converter for the import you are trying to perform and provides an easy way of separating the different importing classes out.

Each MEF part can be built to satisfy an importing interface with some standard methods that convert a row of the import file to your output data or override a base class with the basic functionality.

MEF is an framework for creating a plug-in architecture - its how outlook and Visual Studio are built, all those lovely extensions in VS are MEF parts.

To build a MEF (Managed Extensability Framework) app start with including a reference to `System.ComponentModel.Composition`

Define interfaces to spec out what the converter will do

```
public interface IImportConverter
{
    int UserId { set; }        
    bool Validate(byte[] fileData, string fileName, ImportType importType);
    ImportResult ImportData(byte[] fileData, string fileName, ImportType importType);
}
```

This can be used for all the file types you want to import.

Add attributes to a new class that define what the class will "Export"

```
[Export(typeof(IImportConverter))]
[MyImport(ImportType.Address, ImportFileType.CSV, "4eca4a5f-74e0")]
public class ImportCSVFormat1 : ImportCSV, IImportConverter
{
 ...interface methods...
}
```

This would define a class that will import CSV files (of a particular format : Format1) and has a custom attributes that sets MEF Export Attribute Metadata. You'd repeat this for each format or file type you want to import. You can set custom attributes with a class like:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ImportAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public ImportAttribute(ImportType importType, ImportFileType fileType, string customerUID)
        : base(typeof(IImportConverter))
    {
        ImportType = importType;
        FileType = fileType;
        CustomerUID = customerUID;
    }

    public ImportType ImportType { get; set; }
    public ImportFileType FileType { get; set; }
    public string CustomerUID { get; set; }
}
```

To actually use the MEF converters you need to import the MEF parts you create when your converting code is run :

```
[ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
protected internal Lazy<IImportConverter, IImportMetadata>[] converters { get; set; }
AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
```

`catalog` collects the parts from a folder, default is app location.

`converters` is a lazy list of the imported MEF parts

Then when you know what sort of file you want to convert (`importFileType` and `importType` ) get a converter from the list of imported parts in `converters`

```
var tmpConverter = (from x in converters
                    where x.Metadata.FileType == importFileType
                    && x.Metadata.ImportType == importType 
                    && (x.Metadata.CustomerUID == import.ImportDataCustomer.CustomerUID)
                    select x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Metadata.CustomerUID).FirstOrDefault();

if (tmpConverter != null)
{
     var converter = (IImportConverter)tmpConverter.Value;
     result = converter.ImportData(import.ImportDataFile, import.ImportDataFileName, importType);
....
}
```

The call to `converter.ImportData` will use the code in the imported class.

Might seem like a lot of code and it can take a while to get your head round whats going on but its extremely flexible when it comes to adding new converter types and can even allow you to add new ones during runtime.

Comment: I haven't heard of MEF before. What is it?

Comment: @jao check out [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) for a full explanation. Added some example MEF stuff to my answer.

Comment: This is an excellent way to kick off into MEF. +1

Comment: MEF is a technology, not a design pattern. No `-1` from me as the underlying idea still makes sense and relies on a strategy pattern ruled by the `IImportConverter` interface.

Answer (score 0):

> What is an appropriate design pattern to solve this problem?

C# idioms involve using the built in serialization framework to do this. You annotate the objects with metadata, and then instantiate different serializers that use those annotations to rip out data to put into the right form, or vice versa.

Xml, JSON, and binary forms are most common, but I would not be surprised if others already exist in a nice packaged form for you to consume.

Comment: Well, this works well if you are free to use your own file format, but I guess this approach will fail for complex, predefined formats like XSLX, which means MS Excel files in compressed XML format.

Comment: I can map a line of an Excel file to an object, but I would need to copy and adapt that method to the XML and CSV readers. And I'd like to keep the code as clean as possible...

Comment: @docBrown - howso? Conceptually, turning an object into a series of cells in Excel isn't really any different from turning it into an xml document.

Comment: @Telastyn: you say you can use *the built in serialization framework* of the .NET framework to read XLSX format? If that would be true, libraries like the Open XML SDK or NPOI were obsolete.

Comment: @docbrown: my apologies, you are correct - I keep forgetting that there's no common serializer base class since that's one of the first things that gets done in any codebase I work in.